# If no push opcode, how does item still end up on stack (tx verification)

Tags: script, opcodes

I was reading the following [link](https://developer.bitcoin.org/devguide/transactions.html#p2pkh-script-validation) and there it says: "Alice’s pubkey script then pushes the pubkey hash that Bob gave her for the first transaction". I mean how ? there's no opcode for that. The previous opcode was OP_HASH160 which pushed hashed public key, after this, there's no PUSH opcode, so how does pubkey hash get pushed again ?

I think I also have another question exactly related to this. In the signature script, does it include push opcodes ? if not, how does signature/public key end up being pushed on stack ? bitcoin.org directly mentions that this is what node executes in order:

```
<sig> <PubKey> OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <PubkeyHash> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG
```

so if there's no push opcode for first 2 items, not sure how they go on stack.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation `< >` implies a push opcode of appropriate length precedes the data item. It's just a convention when writing about Bitcoin scripts.